# Lollipop SAF: how pre-installed file manager is able to write to SD card?

Tags: sd-card, 5.1-lollipop

With SAF I am able to write to external SD card with explicit user permission.  BUT I am wondering how pre-installed File Manager app is able to write to any SD card without user permission? Is the `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` permission making the difference ?

How to gain this type of access ?

I have source code of android for the tablet I have.  Can I add my app to source and compile, so that my app can write to any SD card without explicit user permission?

Comment: Just to add some clarity :  I develop educational apps, which will be bundled along with a tablet device.  Without the 'any SD card write permission', students will have to give explicit permission whenever they use a new SD card. Many application functions would be hampered.

Request to throw some light into this.. Thanks in advance.